# plot FFTW gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How can I make a plot in Gnuplot like those seen here: http://www.fftw.org/accuracy/G4-1.06GHz-gcc3.4/, i.e. with an explicit x axis?  I have a dataset like this:

```
2   1066.7
4   3122.9
8   4715.2
16  5538.5
32  5757.3
64  5891.4
128 5398.3
256 5280.2
512 5178.4
1024    4048.6
2048    4383
4096    3794.4
```

Everytime I plot, the x-axis is a linear scale so all of my values are bunched up against the y axis.  I want each x value to be equally spaced, like in the linked plots. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `fftw` and `python`?

Comment: The plot I am trying to recreate is from FFTW's website, using FFTW benchmark results.  I am using Python to call Gnuplot.  Sorry for improperly using tags.

Comment: No problem.  I removed the tags which are unnecessary.  If you were also looking for a python/matplotlib solution, we could add those tags back on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In gnuplot, you need to tell it to use logscale axes (base 2)

```
set logscale x 2
set xtics 2 #label powers of 2 instead of the default
plot 'dataset.dat' w lines
```

Answer (score 2):

Your x axis should have an logarithmic scale. You can set it with respect to 2 with

```
set logscale x 2
```